# How to write a pointer to std::cerr?

Tags: c++, pointers, iostream, stderr

Given:

```
MY_CLASS* ptr = MY_CLASS::GetSomeInstance();
```

What is the correct way to output `ptr` to `std::cerr`, so I can log its value? Note I don't want to write the class, just the address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator<<` is overloaded to take a `const void*`, so you can simply insert the pointer into the stream:

```
std::cerr << ptr;
```

The exception is that if the pointer is a `const char*`, it will be interpreted as a pointer to a C string.  To print the pointer, you need to cast it explicitly to a `const void*`:

```
std::cerr << static_cast<const void*>(ptr);
```

Comment: Except for the stupid `::std::endl` this is an excellent answer.  You should use `'\n'` instead, especially for `::std::cerr`.

Comment: @Omnifarious:  I just removed it altogether since it's not important to the answer anyway.

Comment: @Omnifarious, what's the beef with endl?  Is it the flush?

Comment: @David - That, and the fact that it's used so often people get the bizarre idea that `'\n'` isn't platform independent and `::std::endl` __has__ to be used.  95% of the time I see `::std::endl` used the flush is totally unnecessary. Flushing is very expensive, and in the case of `::std::cerr` completely superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) for printf like formatting:

```
std::cerr << format("%p", ptr) << endl;
```

`%p` formats pointer - should be portable between x86 and x64.

Comment: How is that better than `cerr << ptr << endl`?

Comment: It's not. Just another option.

Answer (score 1):

While using `operator<<` works, you could also use `<cstdio>`:

```
#include <cstdio>
...
MY_CLASS* ptr = MY_CLASS::GetSomeInstance();
fprintf(std::stderr, "Pointer address: %p", ptr);
```